# Approximating a smooth multidimensional function using Keras to an error of 1e-4

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, regression, approximation

I am trying to approximate a function that smoothly maps five inputs to a single probability using Keras, but seem to have hit a limit. A similar problem was posed here ([Keras Regression to approximate function (goal: loss < 1e-7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48665201/keras-regression-to-approximate-function-goal-loss-1e-7)) for a ten-dimensional function and I have found that the architecture proposed there, namely:

```py
model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(128,input_shape=(5,), activation='tanh'))

model.add(Dense(64,activation='tanh'))

model.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mae')
```

gives me my best results, converging to a best loss of around 7e-4 on my validation data when the batch size is 1000. Adding or removing more neurons or layers seems to reduce the accuracy. Dropout regularisation also reduces accuracy. I am currently using 1e7 training samples, which took two days to generate (hence the desire to approximate this function). I would like to reduce the mae by another order of magnitude, does anyone have any suggestions how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend use utilize the keras callbacks ReduceLROnPlateau, documentation is [here](https://keras.io/api/callbacks/reduce_lr_on_plateau/) and ModelCheckpoint, documentation is [here.](https://keras.io/api/callbacks/model_checkpoint/). For the first, set it to monitory validation loss and it will reduce the learning rate by a factor(factor) if the loss fails to reduce after a fixed number (patience) of consecutive epochs. For the second also monitor validation loss and save the weights for the model with the lowest validation loss to a directory. After training load the weights and use them to evaluate or predict on the test set. My code implementation is shown below.

```
checkpoint=tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=save_loc, monitor='val_loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True,
        save_weights_only=True, mode='auto', save_freq='epoch', options=None)
lr_adjust=tf.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau( monitor="val_loss", factor=0.5, patience=1, verbose=1, mode="auto",
        min_delta=0.00001,  cooldown=0,  min_lr=0)
callbacks=[checkpoint, lr_adjust]
history = model.fit_generator( train_generator, epochs=EPOCHS,
          steps_per_epoch=STEPS_PER_EPOCH,validation_data=validation_generator,
          validation_steps=VALIDATION_STEPS, callbacks=callbacks)
model.load_weights(save_loc) # load the saved weights
# after this use the model to evaluate or predict on the test set.
# if you are satisfied with the results you can then save the entire model with
model.save(save_loc)
```

Comment: Thank you. This didn't help with my original architecture, but it did allow me to train a deeper network to have better results using this callback with sgd. I am still not quite at my goal in terms of accuracy, but will keep experimenting.